# jQuery Countdown format display hours if hour is zero

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Can anyone here look into my jquery code. This is from a Magento extension. By default it doesn't show the number of hours if the hour is zero. What I want is for it to display 00 if the countdown is less than an hour. And that's it. Here's my current jquery code. It display HH:MM:SS if it's more than an hour, but if it's less than an hour, it only display MM:SS.

```
 var result = new Array();
         var flag   = false;
         for (i in diff) {
             if ((i == 'seconds' || i == 'minutes' || i == 'hours') && diff[i][0] == 0) {
                 result.push('00' + options.lang[i][options.lang.plurar(diff[i][0])]);
             } else {
                 if (flag) {
                     diff[i][0]--;
                     flag = false;
                 }

                 if (diff[i][0] < 0) {
                     flag = true;
                     diff[i][0] += diff[i][1];
                 }

                 if (!diff[i][0]) {
                     continue;
                 }

                 if (i == 'days' && diff[i][0] < 0) {
                     diff['days'][0] = Math.abs(1 + diff['days'][0]);
                     diff['months'][0]++;
                 }

                 if(i == 'years' && diff[i][0] < 0) {
                     return '';
                 }

                 if ((i == 'seconds' || i == 'minutes' || i == 'hours') && diff[i][0] < 10) {
                     diff[i][0] = '0' + diff[i][0];
                 }    

                 if (diff[i][0] != 0) {
                     result.push(diff[i][0] + '' + options.lang[i][options.lang.plurar(diff[i][0])]);
                 }
             }
         }
```

Comment: I tried copy paste it on fiddle but it doesn't display anything. Hahaha. Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/X7j9C/ . Maybe i did something wrong. My countdown shows HH:MM:SS sometimes, but sometimes it doesn't which is really weird. The live countdown is in here in my staging site: http://shopaholiq.jehzhost.com/

Comment: this code doesn't seem to be complete. please check and its unclear

Comment: I tried including the external sources and the countdown started. Still figuring out how can I replicate my problem before. It display properly now: http://jsfiddle.net/X7j9C/2/ I will try to replicate the problem again and will update this post.